# How can I utilise 2 attributes on each edge in a weighted undirected graph?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I am using networkx in python and have a basic weighted undirected graph. I am simulating drone delivery services and will need distance and traffic values on the edges, then urgency values on the nodes. I will be applying an A* search algorithm with a slightly modified hueristic.

So my question is, is there any way i can use 2 attributes on the edges or should i just combine them? and is lowering the hueristic value for higher urgency a sensible choice?

My thinking is that when i initialise a start and goal node, i will get the goal nodes 'urgency' value (which is 1 to 5) and the higher the value, the lower my hueristic value in A* will be. Hopefully speeding up the process by edging closer to the results of a greedy best first search. Then in terms of edge weights, i see no reason to not combine the distance and traffic attributes to create 1 weight, although thats because i am not sure what else i can do with 2 attributes on the edges in this scenario. The weight will be 1 to 10 and the traffic 1 to 5.

Comment: Take a step back.  Why are you using A*?  If you know all the weights before you start, then Dijkstra is simpler and faster.